# Django __exact queryset filter - case sensitivity not working as expected

Tags: django, django-queryset, case-sensitive

I am trying to filter a Django queryset where the case should be sensitive, although I am not getting the results I expect from the "__exact" filter, which I believe to be case-sensitive:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/

My code looks like this:

```
lower_case_test = MyObject.objects.filter(name__exact="d")
for item in lower_case_test:
    print("item.name: ", item.name)
```

I have 2 in the "MyObject" model, one with name "d" and one with name "D".

The output of the above code is:

> (u'item: ', u'D') (u'item: ', u'd')

Can anyone suggest what might be the issue here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding all() to your query `lower_case_test = MyObject.objects.all().filter(name_exact="d") `

Comment: Hi @ChristopherHolder - thanks for the suggestion. Have just tried, but no difference.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu MySQL

Answer (score 2):

The __exact and __iexact queries are case insensitive if you are using the SQLLite DB.

To get the functionally correctly, change the Collation of the MySql database to latin1_swedish_cs or utf8_bin for case sensitive comparisons.

Check the link for detailed solution.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2170

Answer (score 1):

I supposed you made a typo in the filter because it should be two underscores between `name` and `exact`.

Some database cannot do exact match on strings and will answer you results in any lower/upper-cases.

What is you database and database config?

More info in [django note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#exact)

You can find out by doing your query in django shell (`./manage.py shell`) and ask for the sql statements:

```py
from logging import getLogger, DEBUG, StreamHandler
l = getLogger('django.db.backends')
l.setLevel(DEBUG)
# l.addHandler(StreamHandler())  # shouldn’t be necessary
list(MyObject.objects.filter(name__exact="d"))
```

With this, you can try to play it directly in your database and better understand what’s going on (you can use `./manage.py dbshell`)

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing out the typo, I've updated my question (this was only a typo on SO, not in the code). I'm using 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', as my DB. With standard MySQL config